# Group by Multiple Columns and add values to original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'Pipe Diameter': [10,10,20,30,20,40,60,20,30],
    'Material': ['DI', 'DI', 'Plastic', 'DI', 'CI', 'Plastic', 'DI', 'CI', 'Plastic'],
    'Length': [1,5,2,7,6,4,9,3,5]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[image]

After grouping the data by 'Pipe Diameter', 'Material' and adding a GROUP ID:

```
# Group data
df_groups = df.groupby(['Pipe Diameter', 'Material']).sum().reset_index()
# Add Group ID
df_groups['Group ID'] = df_groups.index

df_groups
```

[image]

Now I need to add the 'Group ID' column into the original dataframe,expecting this result:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `df['Group ID'] = df.groupby(['Pipe Diameter', 'Material']).ngroup()`

Comment: Thanks! while writing the question I realised I can just merge both df, but this is way useful!

Comment: @jezrael surprised you didn't close it as a dupe of the question you answered! :) I've corrected (and closed the other one as a dupe of that too)

Comment: @Nick - I use google for find `pandas ngroup` here ;)

Comment: @jezrael me too - yours was the first result for me... guess ordering is upside-down in Australia :)